# Java: How to create a LinkedList of Class types that all must derive from a specific type?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a linked list of class types, where every entry in the list must derive from a specified type.  Here is my current attempt, where `Rigidbody` is a class that extends `Component`:

```
LinkedList<Class<Component>> required = new LinkedList<Class<Component>>();
required.add( Rigidbody.class );
```

Results in error:

```
The method add(Class<Component>) in the type LinkedList<Class<Component>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Rigidbody>)
```

It seems to be expecting the exact `Component` class only, and it's not supporting sub-types.  I have tried parameterizing it as `Class<T extends Component>` but that syntax only seems to work for methods.

Is there anyway I can achieve this without falling back to a non-specific `LinkedList<Class>` type?

Comment: `LinkedList<Class<? extends Component>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration `List<Class<Component>>` is invariant (it would only accept `Class<Component>`) and you need to make it covariant so that it can accept subtypes.

```
    LinkedList<Class<? extends Component>> required = new LinkedList<>();
    required.add(Rigidbody.class);
```

Have a look at PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super) in Effective Java book.